# Where to find ".NET CLR Memory"

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to monitor "# Bytes in all Heaps" counter under ".NET CLR Memory" for the following instances:

sqlservr
SQLAGENT90
MsDtsSrvr (Depending on whether you run SSIS)
(*Global*) (To get the sum of all memory usage)

But I don't know where to find it.

Comment: That sounds like a Performance Monitor (perfmon) counter.  Note: Linking to where you found that information might help to give your question context.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen all of them at (.NET CLR Memory/# Bytes in all Heaps) instances collection now. May be you have problems with installation or permissions? There are causes of the counter's missing https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverfaq/2009/03/17/what-should-we-do-when-the-sql-server-performance-counters-are-missing/

Answer (score 0):

On the Start Menu
1. Type `Performance Monitor`
and it will look like this:

[image]

Click the `Addition` Sign

[image]

As you can see the .Net CLR Memory
Click Add Sign on the right click it.

And Click Button to Add in Monitoring then click Ok when Done

Comment: If this helped your problem you can mark this as answered.